# How can I remove the comma between volume and number in the IEEEtr.bst file

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I just started modifying my `ieeetr.bst` file.

I was able to switch first and last name for my (journal article) authors in the bibliography. I also wanted to display the Volume and Issue number as `1(1)` and not `vol. 1, no. 1`. So far I only got to `1, (1)`.

Any ideas how I can get rid off the space and comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your copy of `ieeetr.bst` you probably modified the function `format.volume` into

```
FUNCTION {format.volume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    %{ "vol.~" volume * } %% original
    { volume }
  if$
}
```

and the function `format.number` into

```
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    %{ "no.~" number * }   %% original
    { "(" number * ")" * } %% new
  if$
}
```

To get rid of the comma and the space between volume and number we have to tell BibTeX that we are not in the middle of a "sentence" by specifying a different output state:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.volume output
      month empty$
    { before.all 'output.state := %% added
    format.number output }
    'skip$
      if$
      format.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: Thanks! great help! I found `SageH.bst` has a function `FUNCTION {add.blank} {  " " * before.all 'output.state := }` making it easier. I could just write (in my case) `format.url output \ add.blank \ format.urldate output`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`custom-bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package.

It starts to work with a generic `.bst` file and produces a customized one. Command `latex makebst.tex` will ask you a big amount of questions to define every parameter of your bibliography style.

May be you will need to run it twice or more before you get the desired result but, at least for me, this solution was easier then learning how are `.bst` files coded.