# Hack of .bst to add urldate in @misc in BibTex with natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, urls, isodate, urlbst

Trying to add `urldate` to my bst-file.

I have the entry as:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    ...
    url
    urldate
    ...
    year
  }
```

With the two functions defining `url` and `urldate`:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ urldate duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "~(Accessed: " * urldate * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

And last, the function `misc`:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.annote output
  format.eprint output
  format.url output
  format.urldate output
  fin.entry
}
```

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=UKenglish,danish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents,url}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{DenTool2015,
author = {{The Engineering ToolBox}},
title = {{Density and Specific Weight of Air at Standard Atmospheric Pressure -- SI Units}},
url = {http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-density-specific-weight-d_600.html},
urldate = {2015-03-30},
year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{DenTool2015}
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Here is the bst-file:
https://db.tt/NUW5iXqF

I get this:
[image: PDF]

Here you can see two `urldate` entries. Hope you can help, removing the first one.
/Tobias

---

Comment:

After the help from Boris, I got the `urldate` to work. If you want to edit the date-format to UK or EU standards, use the `isodate` packages.

Ex:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\url{" swap$ * "}" * 
        urldate duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ }
        { "~(Date last accessed:~\numdate\printdate{"  swap$ * "})" * *}
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

will give:
[image: pdf]

Comment: You tagged this `urlbst`. Note that the `.bst` files generated by `urlbst` include a `lastchecked` field which is formatted in a broadly similar way to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two errors in your hack.

First, you leave urldate on stack after your `if$` statement.  This is how you get two dates.  You need to use this instance with `swap$` instead of putting the third instance of `urldate` on stack:

```
FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ urldate duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "~(Accessed: " swap$ * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

However, if you make this change, you will see that url and date are separated by comma: `url, (Accessed: urldate)`.  I guess it is not what you want.  So I suggest deleting `format.urldate` altogether and putting `urldate` into `format.url` instead like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\url{" swap$ * "}" * 
        urldate duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ }
        { "~(Accessed: "  swap$ * ")" * *}
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

This takes care of the case where you have `urldate` but not `url` (a good software must gracefully deal with users' mistakes).

The result is

The Engineering ToolBox, 2015: Density and Specific Weight of Air at Standard
  Atmospheric Pressure ­ SI Units. http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-density-specific-weight-d_600.html (Accessed: 2015-03-30).

Comment: Perfect, I had a suspicion that it was the `duplicate$`, `swap$` or `* urldate *`, which was giving me the headache. Thanks alot!

Comment: The comma can be removed by another trick: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120146/151159). Maybe your suggestion is cleaner.

Comment: btw, I would suggest a space, rather then a ~, because I don't see why a line break woudn't be allowed there.

Comment: When using this approach, I get the result: The Engineering ToolBox, 2015: Density and Specific Weight of Air at Standard Atmospheric Pressure ­ SI Units. (Accessed: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-density-specific-weight-d_600.html), with no date. What gives?

Comment: For this to work, "urldate" needs to be included as an ENTRY in the .bst file (maybe this is trivial but I was struggling with it for hours).