# URLDATE format issue

Tags: bibtex

I have a complex document using a modified version of the bib style IEEEtran.bst, which can be found here: https://github.com/ionaic/bibtex-ieeetran-urldate

I think I am using bibtex, but it could be biblatex, I'm not sure the difference.

My problem is that when the bibliography is generated the urldate displays as "2016-02-03". 
I want it to be displayed as "February 3, 2016"

Here is a MWEB. You'll have to download IEEEtran.bst (from the link above) and put it in your directory, but this should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn, twoside, notitlepage, openany]{book}
%Preamble
\usepackage{cite}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{mr_ieee_????,
        title = {{{IEEE Citation Reference}}},
        timestamp = {2016-02-03T19:11:17Z},
        urldate = {2016-02-03},
        author = {MR, Surname and TA, Xyz},
    }
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    %Citations and text here
    \cite{mr_ieee_????}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranUrldate}
    \bibliography{\jobname} 

\end{document}
```

My preamble DOES NOT INCLUDE: `\usepackage{biblatex}` or similar. I tried adding the following to my preamble from previous investigation of this issue, but it broke my document:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false,language=australian]{biblatex}
```

================================================

Samcarter helped me out here. If you have a large auto-generating library like I do, the only automated way to do this is to edit the IEEEtranURLdate.bst file to include the date format. Here is the exact section of the code including my edit:

```
%% URLDATE

FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ is.use.url
  { urldate empty$
    { "" }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.yes  'status.cap :=
      " (" name.urldate.prefix * " \DTMdate{" * urldate * "})" *
      punct.period 'this.status.punct :=
      %use this line if you want the url to have a period after it before the date accessed
      %punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
      space.normal 'this.status.space :=
      quote.no 'this.status.quote :=
  }
  if$
  }
  {""}
  if$
}
```

As samcarter said, you have to add this to the BST file: **\DTMdate{" * urldate * "}** and of course, you need to put \usepackage[english]{datetime2} in the preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, and complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: From the code you showed we can categorically say that you are not using `biblatex`, you are using BibTeX and `.bst` files. That is why `\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false,language=australian]{biblatex}` does not work, that is a `biblatex` solution.

Comment: Can you please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? With the code you have given us so far, I don't get an URLdate output at all. The code of `IEEEtran.bst` does not suggest to me that the `urldate` field is used at all.

Comment: I get no date at all with your example. Did you actually try it?

Comment: Do you use an unmodified version of `IEEEtran.bst`? With the official version, as it is available from ctan, I don't get any date.

Comment: I have to use a modified version, else there is no date. I'm trying to find the reference I got it from, so you can look at it for yourself. Give me some time to find it.

Comment: You can find the modified version of IEEEtran.bst with the URLdate here: https://github.com/ionaic/bibtex-ieeetran-urldate

I'll add it to the OP

Comment: I'm working on a better MWE, but I keep breaking my document.

Comment: okay, added MWEB, but you'll need to download the modified IEEEtran.bst from the link to get it to function properly.

Comment: @Pearl maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236028/36296 could help

Comment: @Pearl `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` should be `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranUrldate}`, that's what the file in the link is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `datetime2` package and add `\DTMdate{...}` to your .bib file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn, twoside, notitlepage, openany]{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mr_ieee_????,
  title = {{{IEEE Citation Reference}}},
  timestamp = {2016-02-03T19:11:17Z},
  urldate = {\DTMdate{2016-02-03}},
  author = {MR, Surname and TA, Xyz},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\cite{mr_ieee_????}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranUrldate}
\bibliography{\jobname} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Complicating the problem, I am using zotero, which auto-generates my bib library and thousands of references; therefore, I would prefer an automatic solution. Is there anyway I can format urldate in IEEEtranUrldate with \DMTdate? Otherwise, this does exactly what I want.

Comment: @Pearl Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236028/36296

Comment: I tried adding \DMTdate{} to the format.urldate function  in the bst file (and \usepackage[english]{datetime2} in the preamble) but that seemed to have no noticeable effect? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: That's it! I had a couple issues, but that's it. Will update OP with exactly what I had to do, but this is basically it.