# Month abbreviations in my bibliography

Tags: bibtex

This is a followup to this thread: [URLDATE format issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376782/urldate-format-issue)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn, twoside, notitlepage, openany]{book}
%Preamble
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{mr_ieee,
        title = {{{IEEE Citation Reference}}},
        timestamp = {2016-02-03T19:11:17Z},
        urldate = {2016-02-03},
        author = {MR, Surname and TA, Xyz},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    %Citations and text here
    \cite{mr_ieee}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranUrldate}
    \bibliography{\jobname} 

\end{document}
```

I am using a modified version of IEEEtran.bst which shows url accessed date. This file can be found here: https://github.com/ionaic/bibtex-ieeetran-urldate

I modified the urldate function in the IEEEtranUrldate.bst file with the following code:

```
%% URLDATE

FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ is.use.url
  { urldate empty$
    { "" }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.yes  'status.cap :=
      " (" name.urldate.prefix * " \DTMdate{" * urldate * "})" *
      punct.period 'this.status.punct :=
      %use this line if you want the url to have a period after it before the date accessed
      %punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
      space.normal 'this.status.space :=
      quote.no 'this.status.quote :=
  }
  if$
  }
  {""}
  if$
}
```

All I did was add \DTMdate around the date to change the style.

This outputs "(Accessed November 23, 2015)", which is fantastic, but I would like the month abbreviated. I looked through datetime2 documentation and many s/e posts, but was not able to solve this problem. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks for your help.