# How to include shortauthor/abbreviations and urldate to a Author-Year bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am looking for a bibliography style that looks like "regstud" (see picture, taken from http://debibify.dorian-depriester.fr/ [here](http://debibify.dorian-depriester.fr/png/regstud-crop.png)), but includes an url, urldate and shortauthor/shorteditor field (or another possibility to add organization abbreviations.

[image: sample of regstud bibliography style]
I tried making my own style with `makebst` but the settings I want cannot be changed in the workflow (you can only add the URL, but no url date and no abbreviations).

I am using BibTeX and natbib in TeXstudio. This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{regstud}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@misc{Esri.2017a,
abstract = {ArcGIS geoprocessing toolset containing tools for classifying 
    rasters via a feature-based approach.},
author = {{Environmental Systems Research Institute, Inc}},
year = {2017},
title = {{An overview of the Segmentation and Classification toolset---Help | ArcGIS for Desktop}},
url = {http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-segmentation-and-classification-tools.htm},
keywords = {ANALYSIS},
urldate = {2018-03-21},
shortauthor = {Esri}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some random text before parenthesis cite \citep{Esri.2017a}. And before cite text \citet{Esri.2017a}.
\bibliography{literature.bib}
\end{document}
```

Inline, the citation is the full name instead of shortname (*Environmental Systems Research Insitute, Inc, 2017*).
[image: citation in text]
The output in the bibliography (using `regstud`) lacks the URL, URL date and abbreviated organization name:
[image: citation in bibliography]

Is there a way to either edit a .bst or a .dbj file (that is generated by `makebst`) in a way that the outcome is as I want it?

Comment: Please add a complete minimal working example of your current document setup.

Comment: I did. I also noticed this warning message: 
`Warning--entry type for "Esri.2017a" isn't style-file defined`. Does that mean that the style doesn't support @www and therefore internet entries?

Comment: Okay, so I found a solution for the urldate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441617/add-urldate-to-url-function-in-bst-file and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236028/hack-of-bst-to-add-urldate-in-misc-in-bibtex-with-natbib.
Is there a similar thing for the abbreviations?
The @www type is really not supported by the style. I changed it to misc which gives the same result.