# Changing custom Bibstyle entry for misc (website)

Tags: bibtex, latex-misc, online, custom-bib, bst

I have a custom bibliographystyle `.bst` file that has been handed down to me, but it isn't formatting an entry for a website as I would like. Currently, the bibtex entry looks like

```
@misc{Stotler,
author = {Stotler, Daren},
title = {{Collisional Radiative Model for Helium}},
year = {2013},
url = {https://w3.pppl.gov/degas2/he{\_}crII.txt},
urldate = {2021-06-17}
}
```

and the entry in my thesis list of references looks like
[image]

How do I make this also show the `url` and the `urldate`? I don't understand `.bst` files at all, and haven't found a tutorial on adding my own entry (that I would then use to ammend the entry in the file already there). Relevant parts of the `.bst` file (or any parts that showed up with ctrl+f of the word misc) gives me

```
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

```
FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
```

Apologies if this is not a MWE as I don't know what parts of the `.bst` file are relevant. How do I alter parts of these entries to include the `url` and `urldate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that in your `ENTRY` list it also includes the fields `url` and `urldate`.

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    ...
    title
    year
    url
    urldate
  }
```

For extracting the information from your entries, you can use the functions written in [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236028/hack-of-bst-to-add-urldate-in-misc-in-bibtex-with-natbib/236077#236077)]. Make sure that these functions are pasted before the `misc` function in the `.bst` file.

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ urldate duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "~(Accessed: " swap$ * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

[1] [Hack of .bst to add urldate in @misc in BibTex with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236028/hack-of-bst-to-add-urldate-in-misc-in-bibtex-with-natbib/236077#236077)

You can then update the function `misc` to output the information in these fields in whichever order you wish as long as they are before `fin.entry`.

'new.block' separates the items with a `.`, otherwise a `,` is used.

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note output
  format.urldate output
  format.url output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

You can also copy Boris' reply from [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236028/hack-of-bst-to-add-urldate-in-misc-in-bibtex-with-natbib/236077#236077)] to have both `url` and `urldate` outputted together i.e. no `,` between the two.

[Tame the BeaST](http://www.lsv.fr/%7Emarkey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf) by Nicolas Markey for further reading on how to customise your '.bst' file to generate the output that you want.

Comment: Perfect answer, worked a treat! Thanks!