# How to customize a .bst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, punctuation

I want to customize this `.bst` [file](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/TeXstuff/utphys.bst).
Now, when I compile a reference it gives me (For an entry of type `@article`):

> Author1, Author2, "Title," Journal Volume (Year) pages, arxiv:0208157.

But I want to make the comma appear after the quotation mark, and I want to replace `arxiv:0208157` with `[hep-ph/0208157]`:

> Author1, Author2, "Title", Journal Volume (Year) pages
>   [hep-ph/0208157].

Here is an MWE:

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
      @article{AA,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},
      arxivId = {hep-th/9605032},
      primaryClass = {hep-th},
      author = {AuthorI, A. and AuthorII, B. and AuthorIII, C.},
      eprint = {9605032},
      journal = {Journal},
      pages = {pages},
      title = {{Title with ?}},
      volume = {Volume},
      year = {Year}
      }
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{document}

  \nocite{*}

  %Bibloography

 \bibliographystyle{utphys}
 \bibliography{test}
 \end{document}
```

**Update:** Concerning the arxiv problem, you have to replace, in the `FUNCTION {format.primaryClass}` of `.bst` file, the code `"{ " [" primaryClass * "]" *}` by  `{ "" primaryClass *}`. And in the function `FUNCTION {format.eprint}` you should replace `"{{\ttfamily " * format.archive * eprint * format.primaryClass * "}}" *}` by `"{{" * " [" * format.primaryClass * "/" * eprint * "]" * "}}" * }`

Now, **I have a new problem**: when the `arxivId` does not contains a **category** e.g. `hep-th`,in `primaryClass = {hep-th}`, the citation printed as `[/9605032]`. So, my new question is how to write it in this case just `[Arxiv:9605032]`?.

**Update II:** The solution is so easy!, I have just to type `"Arxiv"` instead of `""` after `primaryClass empty$`

Comment: Nice work figuring out the answer to the arxiv-related  issue! To help future readers of this posting, you may want to place your solution in a separate answer. I'll be happy to upvote. :-)

Comment: @Mico, I added it, fell free to edit it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply minor modifications to the following two functions, starting on l. 519, in the file `utphys.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ",''" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title.p}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ".''" * }
  if$
}
```

Specifically, change `,''` to `'',` in `format.title`, and change `.''` to `''.` in `format.title.p`.

Note that you shouldn't edit and change an original file from the TeX distribution directly. Instead, make a copy of the file `utphys.bst` and apply the two suggestions given above to the copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the role of `format.title.p`? and what about the arxiv problem ?

Comment: @LlavDem - I suggested the change to `format.title.p` mostly pre-emptively. I'm afraid I don't have much to say about "the arxiv problem".

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem of arxiv papers, first, you have to replace, in the `utphys.bst` file, the code

```
FUNCTION {format.primaryClass}
{
  primaryClass empty$
      { "" }
      { " [" primaryClass * "]" *}
  if$            
}

FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
     { ""}
     { archive empty$
          {"\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/" eprint * "}" * 
             "{{\ttfamily " * format.archive * eprint *
              format.primaryClass * "}}" *}
          {"\href{" archive *  "/" * eprint * "}" * 
             "{{\ttfamily " * format.archive * eprint *
              format.primaryClass * "}}" *}
       if$
     }
     if$
}
```

by the following code:

```
FUNCTION {format.primaryClass}
{
  primaryClass empty$
      { "Arxiv:" } % 
     { "" primaryClass * "/" *}        %Vall { " [" primaryClass * "]" *}
  if$            
}

FUNCTION {format.eprint} % eprint:9605032, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605023
{ eprint empty$
     { "" }
     {  archive empty$
          {"\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/"  format.primaryClass *  eprint * "}" *
             "{{" * " [" * format.primaryClass *                              % vall "{{\ttfamily " * format.archive * eprint *
               eprint * "]" * "}}" * }

          {"\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/"  "}" *
             "{{" * " [" * format.primaryClass *
              eprint * "]" * "}}" *}
       if$
        }
     if$
}
```

Explication:

**I)** in  `format.primaryClass` `{ "" primaryClass * "/" *}` instead of `{ " [" primaryClass * "]" *}`  will replace  `[hep-th]` by `hep-th/`. So it will print `primaryClass/` (printClass is 
the catagory of the paper e.g. `hep-th` ) when it is defined, else (some of arxiv papers do not have a `primaryClass`) it would print `Arxiv:` (If$ will check that).

**II)** in  `format.eprint`:

**A)**: `\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/"  format.primaryClass *  eprint * "}"`: this useful only when you use the `hyperref` package,
 it produces the hyperlink `http://arxiv.org/abs/primerClass/eprint` e.g. if  `primaryClass = {hep-th}` and `eprint = {9605032}` it will produce 
`http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605032`. The code `"{{" * " [" * format.primaryClass * eprint * "]" * "}}" * }` is the hyperlinked printed text which is
`[format.primaryClass eprint]` i.e. in my previous example `[hep-th/9605032]`.  Remark: If you do not use the `hyperref` package this will just print
 `[hep-th/9605032]`.

**B)** : Now, you can guess what the code `"\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/"  "}"` does ?. When the arxiv paper does not have a `primaryClass` the case 
**A)** is omitted and the program will excute this code, so  this is nothing but `\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/format.primaryClass eprint }` and since there is no `primaryClass` the `format.primaryClass` is just `Arxiv:`. e.g. if  `eprint = {1512.00704}` this will give the hyperlink `http://arxiv.org/abs/Arxiv:1512.00704` and you will automatically redirected
to the link `http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00704`. Finally, the code `"{{" * " [" * format.primaryClass *  eprint * "]" * "}}" *` will print the hyperlinked 
text `[format.primaryClass eprint]` which is in our last example `[Arxiv:1512.00704]`.

To remove the comma before `Arxiv` you must replace the following code (as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120146/77432)):

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.collaboration output
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  crossref missing$
  { journal missing$   
        {}
        { format.journal add.doi "journal" output.check}
      if$
    report missing$
        {format.eprint output}
        {blank.sep format.report output format.eprint output}
      if$
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
      format.eprint output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.url output
  new.sentence
  note output
  new.sentence
  format.SLACcitation output
  fin.entry
}
```

by the code:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.collaboration output
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  crossref missing$
  { journal missing$   
        {}
        { format.journal add.doi "journal" output.check}
      if$
    report missing$
         {before.all 'output.state := %% added  
         format.eprint output}
        {blank.sep format.report output format.eprint output}
      if$
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
      format.eprint output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.url output
  new.sentence
  note output
  new.sentence
  format.SLACcitation output
  fin.entry
}
```

**A MWE:**

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
     @article{A,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},
      arxivId = {hep-th/9605032},
      author = {AuthorI, A. and AuthorII, B. and AuthorIII, C.},
      eprint = {9605032},
      journal = {Journal of Bla bla},
      pages = {12},
      primaryClass = {hep-th},
      title = {{Title of the paper A}},
      volume = {123},
      year = {2016}
        }
     @article{B,
      archivePrefix = {arXiv},      
      author = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B. and AuthorC, C.},
      arxivId = {1512.00704},
      eprint = {1512.00704},
      journal = {Journal of bla bla},
      pages = {1233},
      title = {{Title of the paper B}},
      volume = {567},
      year = {2016}
        }
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{document}

   ~\nocite{*}

 %Bibleography

 \bibliographystyle{Vall}
 \bibliography{test}
 \end{document}
```

The result: 
[image]