# Proper arxiv links in bibtex to be uploaded to the arxiv

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, arxiv

The arxiv has [clear instructions](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles) that references to other arxiv preprints should use `archivePrefix="arxiv"`, `eprint = "xxxx.xxxx"`, and `primaryClass="xxxx"`. The goal seems to be that it will output a text string of the primary class, followed by the identifier, which will both link to the correct arxiv page and will be correctly picked up by the automated reference service.

It looks like normal bibliography styles don't accommodate this, but they give the option to download some. However, they don't seem to work. As an example, in the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Test~\cite{test_citation}

\bibliographystyle{hplain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

with test.bib:

```
@misc{test_citation,
    title={Another subexponential-time quantum algorithm for the dihedral hidden subgroup problem},
    author={Greg Kuperberg},
    year={2011},
    eprint={1112.3333},
    archivePrefix={arXiv},
    primaryClass={quant-ph}
}
```

the reference comes out as:

> [1] Greg Kuperberg. Another subexponential-time quantum algorithm for the dihedral hidden subgroup problem, 2011, 1112.3333.

and "1112.3333" is not a hyperlink.

I tried other bibliography style files, but they all seem to have the same problem. I want the reference to look like:

> [1] Greg Kuperberg. Another subexponential-time quantum algorithm for the dihedral hidden subgroup problem, 2011, arxiv:1112.3333.

because when it does, the arxiv's paper compiler will correctly place the link to the paper for "arxiv:1112.3333".

At this point, for this paper, it will probably save time to do this manually for each arxiv reference, but is there some reason it's not happening automatically?

Comment: I see nothing in the bst that indicates that it would support hyperref or links. I suggest that you do what the page says at the end: ask their support.

Comment: Contrary to what the arXiv page seems to suggest `hplain.bst` neither supports the fields `archivePrefix` and `primaryClass` nor does it produce links or an 'arXiv:' prefix before the `eprint` field. The [`urlbst` styles](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst) seem to support `eprint` with links, so you may be happier with `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `hplain.bst` file is intended as a blank starting place for you to build your own linking around - i.e. it doesn't do the linking for you, as defined in the `.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
    { "" }
    { eprint }
  if$
}
```

so the eprint formatting is essentially blank. The question of how to setup linking, has been answered elsewhere (I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296094/how-to-customize-a-bst-file) helpful).