# Remove comma between two fields (instiution and series) in .bst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm trying to format bibtex entries of type `unpublished` (for Working Papers) like those of type `article`. That is, institution + series shall be formatted as if it was the name of the journal.

This is my bibtex entry:

```
@unpublished{SomeKey,
    title = {bst files are difficult},
    year = {2015},
    author = {Author, Unknown},
    series = {Discussion Paper},
    institution = {Bibtex-Institute}
}
```

To do so, I'm tweaking the [`agsm`](http://crpit.com/agsm.bst) style:

```
FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
  if$
  institution emphasize output
  series emphasize output
  new.block
  fin.entry
}
```

which outputs

Author, U. (2015), 'bst files are difficult', *Bibtex-Institute*, *Discussion Paper*. How do I get rid of the comma between the fields institution and series?

The original function was:

```
FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title "title" output.check }
  if$
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

Comment: The answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120146/151159): tell the parser it is not in the middle of a sentence by adding `before.all 'output.state :=` in between.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than modify the bibliography style file `agsm.bst`, I would employ the `note` field with an entry of type `@unpublished` or `@misc`. Which type to employ will depend on whether or not you want the publication's title to be encased in single quotes.

Oh, if the string `Bibtex-Institute Discussion Paper` should be typeset in italics, simply replace

```
note  = {Bibtex-Institute Discussion Paper},
```

with

```
note  = {\emph{Bibtex-Institute Discussion Paper}},
```

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@unpublished{SomeKeyA,
    title = {bst files are difficult},
    year  = {2015},
    author= {Author, Unknown},
    note  = {Bibtex-Institute Discussion Paper},
}
@misc{SomeKeyB,
    title = {bst files are difficult},
    year  = {2016},
    author= {Author, Unknown},
    note  = {Bibtex-Institute Discussion Paper},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Altering the `.bib` file is no option for me, unfortunately: We import it directly from Mendeley.

Comment: @MERose - I don't understand the basis for your comment. Just because the entry is imported via some external program (here:Mendeley) should not imply that you can't change the entry once it's been imported

Comment: Well, that depends on the meaning of import. We do not copy the file. We really can't change the file. That's the point.

Comment: @MERose - Do you want me to delete this answer as it apparently doesn't help you achieve your objective?

Comment: No, of course not! It's a good answer, and definitely helpful for some people.

Comment: I understand the basis for Mico's comment. In my case Mendeley generates the bibtex for 200+ sources (for a book). I don't want to edit them all! Plus, when I add a new source, I would need to repeat the process. No, the bst should be correct.

Comment: @JHBonarius - The solution, then, is to figure out how to instruct Mendeley to do what *you* need it to do. E.g., one has to figure out how to add a field called `note` to some entries. If that's beyond Mendeley's capabilities, it may be high time to give up on Mendeley and to start looking for a different solution.

Comment: @Mico that is *a* solution. I found a better one (imho). See my comment to the OP. And if you know a better solution then mendeley let me know. Until then, mendeley is saving me TONS of time.

Comment: @JHBonarius - If you go down the modify-the-bst-file-since-I-can't-modify-the-bib-entries route, you'll be in hack-the-bst-file purgatory every time you need to switch bibliography styles. And, if you're submitting a paper to a journal or other publisher, you will likely not be authorized to modify their bst file. At that point, you may have to go back to modifying the bib file after all.

Comment: (sorry for the discussion in comments) True. I'm now in contact with SAGE Tex support. Their bst files seem to be outdated, as Harvard reference style went from "URL:" to "Available from: (accessed ...)". I proposed a new SageH.bst (not breaking the existing note/howpublished structures). Maybe they will consider it.